# MVVM bind IsEnabled to multiple bools in ViewModel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm

I have the button below which has it's IsEnabled property bound to a bool in the ViewModel called EnableBtn.

If I have another bool called EnableMail how would I amend this so that the IsEnabled is bound to both?

```
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding EnableBtn, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}" x:Name="SaveSendButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{i18n:Translate SaveAndSend}" Style="{StaticResource bottomButtonsBlue}" Command="{Binding EmailPlanCommand}"></Button>
```

Comment: Bind to a property that returns the logical AND of both bools?

Comment: What stuart says is the correct response.`EnableBtn` clearly relates to the buttons enabled-ness. so the getter of that property should consider the `EnableMail`s value too, if it needs to.

Comment: if I've picked you up right, no need for a multi binding, just bind to one bool and evaluate everything in the get?

Comment: yes. A multibinding really doesn't make much sense in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public bool IsBothEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            if (EnableBtn && EnableMail)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now bind your Button.IsEnabled Property to IsBothEnabled.

Comment: Note that you have to call PropertyChanged("IsBothEnabled") if one of the properties `EnableBtn` or `EnableMail` changed.

Comment: Don't forget that the setter for `EnableBtn` and `EnableMail` should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for themselves as usual, **AND** the composite property `IsBothEnabled`.

Comment: `return EnableBtn && EnableMail` instead of the `if`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to the valid solution from meq, you could use a [multi binding](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv):

The XAML code would look like:

```
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AreAllTrueMultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding Path="EnableBtn" />
        <Binding Path="EnableMail" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.IsEnabled>
```

However, you need a MultiValueConverter similar to:

```
public class AreAllTrueMultiValueConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.OfType<bool>().All();
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot convert back");
    }
}
```

I would prefer the MultiBinding to the additional view model property because it doesn't require "dependent properties" that has to be notified if another property changed. Therefore it results in simpler view model logic.

Comment: I'll upvote this if you can show some XAML. "Link only" answers are discouraged.

Comment: @JanDotNet Please add some XAML.

Comment: To add to this, Xamarin Community Toolkit has a converter specifically for this, `VariableMultiValueConverter`, so you don't even have to make your own. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/variablemultivalueconverter